I want my score increase by 1 every time a piece is matched but the score remains as 1 if the id is different but increase if its the same id
public class SlotScript : MonoBehaviour, IDropHander
{
    public int id;

    private float score = 0;
    public void OnDrop(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("Item Dropped");

        if(eventData.pointerDrag != null)
        {
            if (eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<DragAndDrop>().id == id)
            {
                eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = this.GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition;
                
            }
            else
            {
                eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<DragAndDrop>().ResetPos();
            }
            score += 1;
            Debug.Log("Score is: " + score);
            if (score > 14)
            {
                SceneManager.LoadScene(1, LoadSceneMode.Single);
            }

        }
    }
}

I checked my other script of which it drags and drops the object but none of those were the problem. I just wanted to keep increasing my score even with different id number.

because the code is on each slot? there isnt an overall counter, only each slot going from 0 to 1 when you fill it in

Thanks! that gave me a whole lotta vision

I decided to create another script that counts how many ids that have met the condition if (eventData.pointerDrag.GetComponent<DragAndDrop>().id == id) which now works. I used list as a way to count my other 15 objects with the same script.
public class Counter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<SlotScript> slots; 

    void Start()
    {
        
        slots = new List<SlotScript>(FindObjectsOfType<SlotScript>());
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
        int matchedCount = CountMatchedSlots();

        
        Debug.Log("Matched Count: " + matchedCount);
    }

    int CountMatchedSlots()
    {
        int count = 0;

        
        foreach (SlotScript slot in slots)
        {
            if (slot.IsMatched()) 
            {
                count++;
                if(count == 15)
                {
                    SceneManager.LoadScene(1, LoadSceneMode.Single);
                }
            }
        }

        return count;
    }
}

